# Android login with hashed username and password

Tags: android, authentication, sha1

I'm working on a project where user have to login first in application to use it. And my little problem is that when user enter his username and password, than I have to hash them and send to the server instead of username and password entered by the user. So for now I'm doing something like this :

```
EditText txtUserName = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.username_login_input);
EditText txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.password_login_input);

HttpClient httpclient;
HttpPost httppost;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.rpc.shalqlqlq.com");

postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username_hash", hashUser(txtUserName.getText().toString(),txtPassword.getText().toString())));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_hash", hashPass(txtUserName.getText().toString(),txtPassword.getText().toString())));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
Log.w("Response ","Status line : "+ response.getStatusLine().toString());
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
buffer = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()).getBytes();

public String hashUser(String username, String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
String hashUser = SHA1.Sha1Hash(username);
    String hashPass = SHA1.Sha1Hash(password);
    String luser = hashPass+hashUser;
    String lastUser = SHA1.Sha1Hash(luser);
    return lastUser;
}

public String hashPass(String username, String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
String hashUser = SHA1.Sha1Hash(username);
    String hashPass = SHA1.Sha1Hash(password);
    String lpass = hashPass+hashUser;        
    String lastPass = SHA1.Sha1Hash(lpass);
    return lastPass;
}
```

And it still tells me that username and password are incorrect. I'm pretty sure that hashing is correct because I've already tried it. So can anybody help me to find out where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything is ok, I guess maybe the problem is in getting the username and password from `edittext`.Try to put

```
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username_hash", hashUser(txtUserName.getText().toString(),txtPassword.getText().toString())));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_hash", hashPass(txtUserName.getText().toString(),txtPassword.getText().toString())));
```

in some kind of event. I guess you have a button Login..so you set these params on `onClick` method and I think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, your hashed username and hashed password are identical:

```
public String hashUser(String username, String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String hashUser = SHA1.Sha1Hash(username);
    String hashPass = SHA1.Sha1Hash(password);
    String luser = hashPass+hashUser; // <-- Hashed pass + user
    String lastUser = SHA1.Sha1Hash(luser); // <-- Hashed a second time
    return lastUser;
}

public String hashPass(String username, String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String hashUser = SHA1.Sha1Hash(username);
    String hashPass = SHA1.Sha1Hash(password);
    String lpass = hashPass+hashUser; // <-- Hashed pass + user
    String lastPass = SHA1.Sha1Hash(lpass); // <-- Hashed a second time
    return lastPass;
}
```

Unless the server stores usernames and passwords each as a hashed hash of password and username, then I'm guessing this is where your problem is.

Why not just use something like:

```
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username_hash", SHA1.Sha1Hash(txtUserName.getText().toString())));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_hash", SHA1.Sha1Hash(txtPassword.getText().toString())));
```

Comment: my mistake, username and password are not the same, I just made a mistake when copying and pasting the code here.